# Como fazer uma ação depois que três elementos dinâmicos forem preenchidos com jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho três select que são criados depois que o usuário clica em um botão, ou seja são dinamicos:

```
<select id="cbExercicio"><option value="0"></option></select>
<select id="cbEquipe"><option value="0"></option></select>
<select id="cbResponsavel"><option value="0"></option></select>
```

Estou fazendo assim para quando modificar apenas um deles:

```
$(document).on('change', '#cbExercio', function(){
      // Ação
})
```

Mas quero uma fucnction que seja chamada assim que o usuario preencher os três e eles forem diferentes de zero(que é o primeiro option em branco com valor 0). Como fazer ou qual melhor forma de fazer??

Comment: Em que momento você precisa verificar isso?

Comment: Atualizei bfavaretto

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode verificar o evento `change` dos três selects, iniciando com uma verificação quanto ao valor de cada um deles.

Assim, por exemplo:

```
$(document).on('change', '#cbExercicio, #cbEquipe, #cbResponsavel', function(){
    if(+$('#cbExercicio').val() != 0 && +$('#cbEquipe').val() != 0 && +$('#cbResponsavel').val() != 0) {
       // Ação
    } else {
       // Ao menos um dos selects está com valor 0
    }
});
```

<sup>[Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLycP/)</sup>

Comment: +1 por resolver o problema de forma elegante. Par quem não percebeu, o operador `+` que antecede os valores é uma forma de conversão implícita do valor selecionado para um número.

Comment: @bfavaretto `$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){});` não seria melhor? Se surgir um select a mais não precisa ficar atrelando o evento ao elemento pelo seu id, atrela pelo seu tipo.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi E se houver outros selects na página? Na vida real eu usaria uma classe. Aqui usei IDs para me adequar à marcação original, mas como digo na resposta é só um exemplo.

Comment: @bfavaretto então talvez o cem por cento correto fosse `$(document).on('change', 'select.novosSelects', function(){});` e daí esses selects fossem criados com essa classe.

Answer (score 5):

É possível resolver o problema de forma mais "genérica", isto é, criando uma espécie de **grupo de campos** usando classes CSS.

Um possível HTML ficaria assim:

```html
<select class="meu_grupo" id="cbExercicio"><option value="0"></option><option value="1">1</option></select>
<select class="meu_grupo" id="cbEquipe"><option value="0"></option><option value="1">1</option></select>
<select class="meu_grupo" id="cbResponsavel"><option value="0"></option><option value="1">1</option></select>
```

Então o código fica assim:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.meu_grupo').change(function() {

        //itera sobre os elementos
        var falta_preencher = false;
        $('.meu_grupo').each(function() {
            if (!this.selectedIndex) falta_preencher = true;
        });

        //verifica o resultado
        if (falta_preencher) alert('Preencha todos...')
        else alert('Preencheu todos!');

    })
});
```

Veja o [jsfiddle funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbnet/).

A ideia é colocar um evento de mudança em todos os campos que possuem a classe `meu_grupo` e, quando ocorrer um evento, verificar se todos os campos do mesmo grupo estão devidamente preenchidos.

Obviamente, o tipo de validação e a ação resultante de todos os campos estarem corretos fica a critério da implementação.

Note que vinculei o evento `change` diretamente aos campos com a classe `meu_grupo`, pois isto é mais eficiente que capturar todos os eventos do documento e filtrar apenas os campos desejados. A não ser que você tenha outras razões para o usar o manipulador `on` no documento, dê preferência aos eventos específicos. Segue o mesmo exemplo usando o `on`:

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.meu_grupo',  function() {

        //itera sobre os elementos
        var falta_preencher = false;
        $('.meu_grupo').each(function() {
            if (!this.selectedIndex) falta_preencher = true;
        });

        //verifica o resultado
        if (falta_preencher) alert('Preencha todos...')
        else alert('Preencheu todos!');

    })
});
```

Note também que a validação do meu exemplo fará uma conversão implícita do texto "0" para `false`. O efeito seria o mesmo se o valor do primeiro elemento fosse vazio.

Comment: Gosto da solução mais genérica, mas seu exemplo deveria usar delegação de eventos para atender aos requisitos da pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não vejo restrição na pergunta quanto ao método de captura do evento. O Joao disse que fez daquele jeito para um dos campos, mas não sabe qual é o melhor jeito. De qualquer forma, acrescentei algumas notas com respeito ao motivo pelo qual fiz dessa forma.

Comment: Eu entendi da primeira frase que os campos são injetados no DOM após o carregamento da página, mas a definição do listener seria feita antes (essa última parte eu inferi).

Comment: @bfavaretto Ah, tem razão, provavelmente é este o motivo. Vou alterar minha resposta. Obrigado. (Preciso dormir mais)